# Replacement of the obsolete commande UTL_FILE_DIR

Tags: oracle, logminer

Am a beginner, and i want to use `LogMiner` in Oracle DB 21c, and in one of the steps was to :

> to set UTL_FILE_DIR to use /oracle/database as the directory where the dictionary file is placed

I tried this commande :

```
alter system set UTL_FILE_DIR = 'PATH' scope = spfile
```

But i got this error :(commande is obsolete)

[image]

Is there a replacement for this commande, and please if you have a site with the rest of the steps to setup Logminer it will help alot.

[Site where i found how to setup logminer](https://www.whamtech.com/eiq_product_suite_help/index.htm?page=EIQ_Server_SDK/Other%20Help/Oracle_LogMiner.htm)

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather use official [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sutil/oracle-logminer-utility.html#GUID-DA37874F-6637-4205-AB5C-A8AC1914D018).

If you did, you'd see the following note:

> Note:Prior to Oracle Database 12c Release 2 (12.2), you used the `UTL_FILE_DIR` initialization parameter to specify a directory location. However, as of Oracle Database 18c, the `UTL_FILE_DIR` initialization parameter is desupported. It is still supported for backward compatibility, but Oracle strongly recommends that you instead use **directory objects**.

Comment: I did find this, i just wanted to know if am headed in the right direction. Thanks for you're answer.

Comment: I believe you are :) You're welcome.